# IntelliJ Idea keeps switching project windows on desktop change

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Hi my IntelliJ Idea keeps changing the project window when I move to another virtual desktop and back.

Example:

1. I have Project A, Project B and Project C opened.
2. I'm working on project A.
3. I switch to desktop 2 and back.
4. Now Project B on the foreground instead of Project A.

This behavior is getting really annoying. I keep my Idea projects on different desktops than my browser and I have to constantly switch to the correct project, when switching desktop.

What have I tried:

1. Change Idea Java Environment https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

- AdoptOpenJDK, SAP and bundled runtimes

1. RC version
2. I've asked around and found out, that this is also happening to other people on different linux distros

This happens only for Idea, I would like to solve this issue instead of downgrading.

Info:

- Kubuntu 5.4.0-42-generic, plasmashell 5.18.5

Comment: Please, file a new issue in IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: Am I getting right all the projects are located on the same desktop at first?

Comment: @ArseniyNisnevich yes, they are on the same desktop. I will file the issue.

Comment: @ArseniyNisnevich https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250310